# How to migrate pm2 processes from one server to another?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 for managing node processes on one of the servers.
The package is here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
It is open source and available both on npmjs and GitHub.

I can easily install it every time using: `npm i pm2 -g`
I love pm2, and not just node processes, I write bash scripts and run them as cron under pm2 and I can easily check the logs.

Some commands:

`pm2 --name "process-name" start "bash script.sh"`

`pm2 --name "node-process" start "node main.js"`

`pm2 logs node-process`

`pm2 stop node-process`

`pm2 restart node-process`

There are 2 more commands which are very useful to start pm2 on startup with all the processes automatically.

`pm2 startup` Will generate startup script.

`pm2 save` Will update start script with current processes.

Everything is good. But, today I got into a problem.
I am running all pm2 node processes from a folder `/mnt/node`.
What I want is that I have synced that `/mnt/node` folder to another server and I am trying to find a way to move all pm2 processes automatically to another server without writing each process once again.

May be someone can help.

Comment: "`pm2 startup` Will generate startup script." Why not sync the startup scripts? BTW: never used pm2

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

On the source server:

```
pm2 save
```

copy file saved on `~/.pm2/dump.pm2` to destination server, then:

```
pm2 resurrect
```

Haven't try this between two differents server yet but i think it will be ok.

Comment: I think this should work. But for now I created a `pm2.json` file and added all tasks in that file so that I can restore that file on any server just like `pm2 start pm2.json`.